# Defining my staging and production environments specification for share point 2O13

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

After reading this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx)

I am planning to build my staging [Used mainly for user acceptance testing] and my production environments for SharePoint as follow:-

My system specification is as follow:-

1. we have around sixty internal users which will be accessing the SharePoint site.
2. we have around fifty external users accessing the SharePoint site.

• For the **Staging Environment** I am going to have **Single-tier deployment** which will be running both SharePoint server & SQL server with following specification:-

o    Single server

o    24 GB of RAM

o    4 processors

o    Visual studio 2012 professional & Team Foundation Server 2012.

o    Windows Server 2012

o    SQL server 2012.

o    SharePoint 2013.

•For the **Production Environment** I am going to have **two Tiered environment**, where SharePoint and SQL are on separate machines, with the following specification:-

o    12 GB RAM + 4 processors for the server running SharePoint 2013 server.

o    16 GB RAM + 4 processors for the database server.

o    Windows Server 2012.

o    SQL server 2012 (for the database server only).

o    SharePoint 2013.

So are the above specification for the staging and production environment valid and will be reliable taking into consideration the number of users will be accessing the system [around sixty internal and fifty external users].

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers look like a good place to start but you will need to do some testing to verify that it works for your environment. Amount of usage and number of services can make a big impact on the amount of resources that are needed.

See this article for steps to test the system: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758659.aspx

Comment: thanks for your reply, so technically speaking the resources are good ? But of course i need to test them.

Comment: Yup, the resources look like a good start